# Convert database query from Postgresql to PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to convert an existing select expression in a postgresql query into PHP but appear to be missing part of the calculation.

The relevant field is:

```
task_start_timestamp > timestamp without time zone
```

The expression is:

```
SELECT justify_interval(((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM age(localtimestamp, task_start_timestamp)) * (1 - task_progress)/COALESCE(NULLIF(task_progress, 0), 1))::int || \' seconds\')::interval) AS task_eta
```

My conversion in PHP: (Note I added a select `localtimestamp as local_timestamp` to the query to ensure the calculation is using the same values as the database).

```
$now = strtotime($item['local_timestamp']);
$task_date = strtotime($item['task_start_timestamp']);
$task_age = $now - $task_date;
$task_eta = $task_age * (1 - $item['task_progress']);
```

However, the server is returning a different result.

```
local_timestamp = 2013-02-28 22:53:42.215137
task_start_timestamp = 2013-02-28 22:22:19.255593
task_eta = 00:10:28
php_task_eta = 00:07:50
```

Comment: I can't help but wonder ... why? It looks perfectly reasonable done i the DB.

Comment: Seconding Craig's point, my rule is "let work others have done and tested do most of the work."  Also doing stuff in the db like this is really helpful and often saves CPU time and memory.